# Handling promt on last window close

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

I have an app that has multiple windows. I'm trying to make the program prompt whether I want to quit or not when I close the **last** window. I though about simply handling it this way:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "QApplication::topLevelWindows().size()" << QApplication::topLevelWindows().size();

    if(QApplication::topLevelWindows().size() <= 1)
    {
    QMessageBox::StandardButton resBtn = QMessageBox::question( this, "APP_NAME",
                                                                tr("Are you sure?\n"),
                                                                QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Yes,
                                                                QMessageBox::Yes);
    if (resBtn != QMessageBox::Yes) {
        event->ignore();
    } else {
        event->accept();
    }
    }
}
```

It works fine if I don't rush too much with closing the windows. But if I close them too fast one after another or close them simultaneously via "RMB -> Close All" in taskbar, they close without prompt. The debug I inserted shows that the size of `QApplication::topLevelWindows` is much higher than 1. But if I wait for a couple of seconds before closing the next window, it decreases.

It seems that there is some time between the moment when the window closes and the moment when it is removed from this list.

Is there some way to get the exact amount of windows I have opened at a certain moment?

Or maybe there is a better way to handle the quit prompt on **last** window's destruction?

Comment: In investigating what goes on you must hold open the possibility that windows are not destroyed in the order they accept the close events. I don't know Qt so I can't say, but I would keep that possibility open. I think I that anyway I would do this by keeping my own count of windows that have not accepted close events, instead of a count of windows that exist. I.e., my own count of non-doomed windows.

Answer (score 1):

If all your windows inherit `MainWindow`, you can simply keep a static integer variable in `MinWindow` class which is initially 0. Increment this by 1 in the constructor and decrease it by 1 in `closeEvent()`. Then, get the user confirmation when `onClose()` fired with value equals to 1 in this variable.

If window class differs, You can keep it in some globally accessible variable.

If you use multiple threads, make sure you increase or decrease this variable atomically.